# SmartBreadCrumbs disable Url encoding RouteValues in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to set up SmartBreadCrumbs to follow the Url pattern on my website.

My category urls should look like this... /shop/Category/4/Ladies/Shoes

Shop is the area, Category is the controller, 4 is the id and /Ladies/Shoes is set up as categoryName which are set as route values.

So in my breadcrumb node I have this set out..

```
_node = new MvcBreadcrumbNode("Index", "Category", category.Name, areaName: "Shop") { Parent = _node, RouteValues = new { id = category.Id, categoryName = string.Join("/", categoryNames)} };
```

The problem is that it is url encoding the backslash
https://localhost:7018/shop/Category/4/Women%2FShoes

Is there any way to stop RouteValues being url encoded for this specific segment?

Comment: Did you mean you want `Women/shoes` instead of `/Women%2FShoes` ? This is only the case or anything else also there?

Comment: Yes I want it to show /womens/shoes

Comment: Its `%2F` means there was some special charaters on your route value isn't it?

Comment: The slash being URL encoded to %2F when the link is generated.

Comment: Well, now in `_node ` your have that `%2F` encoded value could you please try to replaced with `/` , this is only the case or you have some other scenario as well?

Comment: The value isn't encoded in the _node object.

Comment: Well, not sure where then you are getting the encoded value, do you have only one case like this? How can it be reproduced?

Comment: There would a simple tricks, the point where you are getting `%2F` we can check the URL and replace the value and finally set the updated URL.

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant way to do this. Since it uses the smartbreadcrumb tag in the html the html structure is never exposed.  There are ways around it such as JavaScript or implementing my own view but was hoping not to have to go this.